# Image Recognition Training

Tags: image-processing

I would like to train an my program to recognize a limited set images say (50-100) distinct objects. Is there an library that will allow me to train for this? So I have maybe 1000 images but they are all of the same 100 distinct objects.  What works well to training to recognize these.

Comment: Have you tried tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html or Theano(CNN with Theano): http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html